# Change title of event from 'start time - end time' to 'start datetime - end datetime' when event spans multiple days

Tags: fullcalendar

When an event in Full Calendar starts at 8:00 and ends at 16:00, that's exactly what it shows in the title in the week view: '8:00 - 16:00'.

But, when the event starts today at 8:00 and ends the day after tomorrow at 16:00, it also shows '8:00 - 16:00' in the title.

I know I can change the format of the title by using:

```
    timeFormat: 'd-M H:mm{ - d-M H:mm}'
```

But what I would really like, is that the date is only showed when the event spans multiple days.

So:

If the event is a one-day event:

```
    timeFormat: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}'
```

If the event is a multiple-day event:

```
    timeFormat: 'd-M H:mm{ - d-M H:mm}'
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but I'll answer it for future reference.

You should use this format:

```
timeFormat: '[d-M ]H:mm{ -[ d-M] H:mm}'
```